# image button is not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

The image button is not shown in a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@color/usualBike"
>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usesLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/tituloUsos"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    /> 

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/disconnect"
        android:layout_width="45dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The horizontal bar and the text appears but the imageButton doesn't.

What can be the problem?

Comment: android:background="@null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you have provided the background to be null here `android:background="@null"` for the ImageButton.

**EDIT**

Change your TextView's width to wrap content.

Comment: Edited my answer. Sorry should have checked it first.

Answer (score 1):

Image Button is not shown because you have set LinearLayout Orienation as Horizontal and then TextView width as "fill_parent" ,change the textview width to "wrap_content" ,your ImageButton will be visible